# Android Button stop taking new action utill onClick() block execution finish

Tags: android, button

```
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()) {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try{
         Thread.sleep(10000);
       }catch(Exception e){}
     }   
  });
```

On above code, I don not want to take any more Button action until the Therad is working. Currently when I press again and again Application ask for force close or wait. I don't want that rather I do not like to take anymore action on this button.

Need help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Add a global boolean and set it to true when u click it. Check for it in your button click. if it is set then return, else run the thread. at the end of the thread set it to false again.

boolean clicked = false;

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()) {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if( clicked )
            return;
        try{
         clicked = true;
         Thread.sleep(10000);
       }catch(Exception e){}
     }   
  });
```

set clicked = false when u return from sleep.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did that earlier, It do the same I mentioned. When I press multiple clicks sometimes later application pops up for Force close or Wait.

Comment: Can u print a few lines to see if the state of "clicked" is maintained properly? Print the state at the place where it is being set true and false. Check if your thread is spawning properly and whether the clicked = false is occurring at the right point. Also be careful where u r setting ure clicked = false; Do it at the point where ure thread returns from sleep.

Comment: @pijushcse you will still get the force close as you are blocking the ui thread for 10 seconds.

Comment: So any solution? is there any way to remove button OnClikListener?

Comment: what exactly are u doing while putting it to sleep? As in whats the big picture?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for your works. And use the `get()` method of `AsyncTask` for your requirement.

Suppose on Button's click `execute()` `AsyncTask` and disable button after wait for `get()` of `AsyncTask` which will return `Result` on completion of AsyncTask and on Result just enable your button again. So you can avoid `ANR` in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to block further clicks while the previous one is being processed:

1) Disable the button at the beginning and re-enable at the end of your `onClick`:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()) {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        b.setEnabled(false);

        //do your stuff

        b.setEnabled(true);
    }   
});
```

2) Set a flag in the beginning of your `onClick` and clear it in the end:

(class-level)

```
boolean isInOnClick = false;
```

and then

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()) {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(!isInOnClick) {
            isInOnClick = true;

            //do your stuff

            isInOnClick = false;
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: What if the stuff between `b.setEnabled(false)` and `b.setEnabled(true)` is executed in a new forked thread? Does the button wait for the completion of this thread before it is enabled again?